# Difference between , and + when printing output

Tags: python, string

Quick and probably dumb question.  When I need to join text and numerical values for output, I would typically use:

```
number = 4
print("Two plus two = " + str(number))
```

But sometimes I see:

```
number = 4
print("Two plus two =",number)
```

The second example does not require type casting and adds a leading space, but otherwise they do the same thing.  Anyone know why there are two ways of doing the same thing?  Which method is 'better'?

Comment: I guesstimate that the second example has better performance in the long run since string concatenation may be expensive.

Comment: using `+` operator you can add multiple spaces and using `,` you can just add single space.

Comment: @KOD . . . They don't "do the same thing".  They happen have the same (or similar) effects.  The first creates a single string which is then output.  The second outputs two different elements.  Commonly, the first method is used with `format()`.

Answer (score 6):

It is important to understand that in `print("Two plus two = " + str(number))` the concatenation operation has nothing to do with `print` and happens before `print` is called.

Let's do some timings:

```
from timeit import Timer

def with_concat():
    print("Two plus two = " + str(4))

def no_concat():
    print("Two plus two =", 4)

print(min(Timer(with_concat).repeat(100, 100)))
print(min(Timer(no_concat).repeat(100, 100)))
```

Outputs

```
0.0006760049999998685
0.0013034899999999627
```

Counter-intuitively (see my comment to the question, string concatenation may be expensive) the example with concatenation is actually faster (by a factor of 2!) in a reproducible manner. But why?

let's inspect the byte code:

```
from dis import dis

def with_concat():
    print("Two plus two = " + str(4))

def no_concat():
    print("Two plus two =", 4)

dis(with_concat)
```

outputs

```
 0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
 2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Two plus two = ')
 4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (str)
 6 LOAD_CONST               2 (4)
 8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
10 BINARY_ADD
12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
14 POP_TOP
16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
18 RETURN_VALUE
```

While

```
dis(no_concat)
```

outputs

```
 0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
 2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Two plus two =')
 4 LOAD_CONST               2 (4)
 6 CALL_FUNCTION            2
 8 POP_TOP
10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Judging by the byte code it also looks like `no_concat` should be faster (shorter, simpler code).

The delay must come from the C source code (in the case of CPython at least).

Let's look at the relevant lines:

```
static PyObject *
builtin_print(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    .
    .
    .

    for (i = 0; i < PyTuple_Size(args); i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            if (sep == NULL)
                err = PyFile_WriteString(" ", file);
            else
                err = PyFile_WriteObject(sep, file,
                                         Py_PRINT_RAW);
            if (err)
                return NULL;
        }
        err = PyFile_WriteObject(PyTuple_GetItem(args, i), file,
                                 Py_PRINT_RAW);
        if (err)
            return NULL;
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

To me it seems like the overhead of using `print(*args)` is due to the repetitive calls to `PyTuple_GetItem(args, i)`, and that the benefit of using it over `print(a + lot + of + concatenated + strings)` is there only when the number of  concatenated strings is large enough to make the concatenation the bottleneck (ie slower than the repetitive calls to `PyTuple_GetItem(args, i)`).

Answer (score 0):

As @DeepSpace commented, using the + operator concatenating the strings, using two args just prints the strings one by one using the *sep* argument as a seperator (default of blank space).
For further information you can check the Python 3.4 [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1592).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but I'll try to answer this in a simpler way as I once had the exact same doubt. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach and please correct me if I'm wrong.

So if you check the python print function documentation:

> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False).
> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed by end. sep, end, file, and flush, if present, must be given as keyword arguments.
>
> ***All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does*** and
> written to the stream, separated by sep and followed by end.

For example let's check a sample code:

```
age = 21
name = "Swapneil"
str1 = "Name is: "+name"+" and age is: "+str(age)

print(str1)
print("Name is:",name,"and age is",age)
```

The output of both print statements is same here, but in the first print str1 is a single object as the strings are concatenated and it requires a type case where required. However, in the second print statement as all non-keyword arguments are "," separated. It will convert all the arguments into string separated by default value of sep argument and throw the same result.

The only difference here is str1 is a single object and in the second print there are multiple objects (The first argument of print function is *objects) it can take as many positional arguments as we give.